# How to write setup build date to a property

Tags: wix

**Update 2:** The [feature request](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/4213/) has been declined, simply because WiX cannot support these "fake" variables cmd.exe offers. So the accepted answer below remains the best solution.

**Update:** I have issued a feature request for adding preprocessor dynamic environment variable support. As soon as the devs respond, I'll update this thread.

---

*Original Question:*

I want to write the date when the setup has been built to a property.

```
<Property Name="BuildDate" Value="$(env.Date)" />
```

or

```
<Property Name="BuildDate" Value="$(sys.Date)" />
```

throws CNDL0150: "Undefined preprocessor variable" while

```
<Property Name="BuildDate" Value="[Date]" />
```

will of course write the string "[Date]" to the MSI property.

How can I achieve this?

Edit: I've tried "Date" in all cases, same result. Also, adding a new environment variable called "BuildDate" and setting it to "%DATE%" removes the compilation error, but the value written to the MSI doesn't resolve to the actual date, instead it yields the string "%DATE%".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try to use all uppercase `DATE`, like this:</strike>

```
<Property Name="BuildDate" Value="$(env.DATE)" />
```

**UPDATE**: My initial guess was not correct - environment variables are case-insensitive when referenced this way.

It seems like it depends on the type of the environment variable. There are standard environment variables, like `%TEMP%`, `%windir%`, etc. Those are "static", meaning the value is not calculated each time you reference it.

There are dynamic environment variables, which are calculated each time they are referenced. These include `%DATE%`, `%TIME%`, etc. It seems that WiX preprocessor can't work with dynamic variables. You can verify this: put `$(env.windir)` and it will work, put `$(env.time)` - and it won't. More info about environment variables can be found [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html).

I have not verified whether there's a wish in WiX bug database to support this. Feel free to do it yourself.

So, back to your question. You can work around this limitation in the following way:

- Create preprocessor extension
- Reference the value from that extension instead of addressing environment variable direcly

The sample how to create preprocessor extension can be found [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/extension_development_preprocessor.html).

Here's a sample of the code which does the job:

```c#
   public class DateExtension : PreprocessorExtension
   {
     public override string[] Prefixes
     {
       get
       {
         return new[] { "date" };
       }
     }

     public override string GetVariableValue(string prefix, string name)
     {
       string result = null;

       switch (prefix)
       {
         case "date":
           switch (name)
           {
             case "Now":
               result = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
               break;
           }
           break;
       }

       return result;
     }
   }
```

And in your WiX code you can use it in the following way:

```
<Property Id="BuildDate" Value="$(date.Now)" />
```

Don't forget to:

- pass preprocessor extension DLL to the WiX setup project (`-ext path/to/PreprocessorExtension.dll`)
- add `[assembly: AssemblyDefaultWixExtension(typeof(PreprocessorWixExtension))]` to the preprocessor extension project

Here is the result I observe in the MSI package:

[image: resulting MSI package]

Comment: I've tried "Date" in all cases, unfortunately the error stays the same: CNDL0150. WiX version is 3.8.1125.0.

Comment: That error you mentioned - does it point to `$(env.date)` as undefined preprocessor variable? Anyway, it sounds like an issue with that particular WiX build - you can try it on stable 3.7 instead.

Comment: Yes, it does. Filename and line number is correct. I've tried it with the latest stable 3.7 release as you suggested - same result: C:\test\WixProjects\_Global\Global_Product.wxs(56,0): error CNDL0150: Undefined preprocessor variable '$(env.DATE)'.

Comment: @Hannes, I've updated my answer - please take a look

Comment: Implementing a preprocessor extension as you suggested works. For the time being, this is the best solution (another workaround would be writing the date to a wxi include file in the prebuild event with an external tool and to reference this in the actual project). Thanks very much for your effort.

Answer (score 9):

You can add a property in you wix project (.wixproj) in your first property group, for example (you can format the date and/or time to your liking):

```
<Date>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm"))</Date>
```

Then in your configurations property groups add this property in `<DefineConstants>`, if you have more constants then separate them with semicolon `;`:

```
<DefineConstants>Date=$(Date)</DefineConstants>
```

Lastly add the MSI Property:

```
<Property Id="BuildDate" Value="$(var.Date)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To set property value from another property use the following syntax:

```
<SetProperty Id="BuildDate" Value="[Date]" After="InstallInitialize" />
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the original question

Comment: Right, I confused build date with the installation one. My bad.